# @Query: function ll_to_earth(double precision, double precision) does not exist

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement the following query in order to fetch places within a certain radius (in meters) given a location (lat,lng):

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "places", path = "places")
public interface PlaceRepository extends JpaRepository<PlaceEntity, Long> {

    @Query(value = "" +
            "SELECT p " +
            "FROM PlaceEntity p " +
            "WHERE earth_distance( " +
            "   ll_to_earth(p.latitude, p.longitude), " +
            "   ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude) " +
            ") < radius")
    List<PlaceEntity> findByLocationAndRadius(@Param("latitude") Float latitude,
                                              @Param("longitude") Float longitude,
                                              @Param("radius") Integer radius);
}
```

However, running it will throw:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function ll_to_earth(double precision, double precision) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 343
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2003)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:161)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 76 more
```

I have also tried to change set `nativeQuery = true` as well as changing the `@Query` to

```
@Query(value = "" +
        "SELECT p " +
        "FROM PlaceEntity p " +
        "WHERE FUNCTION('earth_distance', " +
        "   FUNCTION('ll_to_earth', p.latitude, p.longitude), " +
        "   FUNCTION('ll_to_earth', latitude, longitude) " +
        ") < radius")
```

with the same result.

What is the right syntax for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From https://johanndutoit.net/searching-in-a-radius-using-postgres/ I found that I have to install some extensions:

Start `psql` shell:

```
psql postgres -h localhost -d <database-name>
```

Execute:

```
<database-name>=# CREATE EXTENSION cube;
<database-name>=# CREATE EXTENSION earthdistance;
```

Further, set `nativeQuery = true` and reference parameters correctly:

```
@Query(value = "" +
        "SELECT * " +
        "FROM place " +
        "WHERE earth_distance( " +
        "   ll_to_earth(place.latitude, place.longitude), " +
        "   ll_to_earth(:latitude, :longitude) " +
        ") < :radius", nativeQuery = true)
List<PlaceEntity> findByLocationAndRadius(@Param("latitude") Float latitude,
                                          @Param("longitude") Float longitude,
                                          @Param("radius") Integer radius);
```

**Note:** This can get slow. The [link](https://johanndutoit.net/searching-in-a-radius-using-postgres/) shows how to improve the performance if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS cube
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS earthdistance

For anyone who needs a JPA version of the same

```
 @Query(
        """
                FROM Place pl
                WHERE 
                FUNCTION('cube_contains',
                 FUNCTION('earth_box',
                  FUNCTION('ll_to_earth', :latitude, :longitude),
                  :radiusInMeters),
                 FUNCTION('ll_to_earth', pl.latitude, pl.longitude) 
                  ) = TRUE
                """)
    fun getPlacesNear(
        pageable: Pageable,
        @Param("latitude") latitude: Double,
        @Param("longitude") longitude: Double,
        @Param("radiusInMeters") radiusInMeters: Int
    ): Page<Place>
```

This works like a charm with paging and distance support

For some weird reason

```
@Query(
        """
                FROM Place pl
                WHERE 
                 FUNCTION('ll_to_earth', pl.latitude, pl.longitude)                    
                 < FUNCTION('earth_box', FUNCTION('ll_to_earth', :latitude, :longitude), :radiusInMeters)
                """)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/cube.html#CUBE-GIST-OPERATORS

For some weird reason '<' does not work expectedly because the '<' is not interpreted correctly in postgres and is giving wrong results.

For postgres you need '@<' symbol which is not interpreted by spring JPA so I had to  switch to using cube_contains function

To get results without pagination -

```
@Query(
            """SELECT *, earth_distance(ll_to_earth(:latitude, :longitude), ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude)) as distance
                    FROM place
                    WHERE  (earth_box(ll_to_earth(:latitude, :longitude), :radiusInMeters) @> ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude))
                    ORDER BY distance ASC
                    """, nativeQuery = true)
        fun getPlacesNear(
            @Param("latitude") latitude: Double,
            @Param("longitude") longitude: Double,
            @Param("radiusInMeters") radiusInMeters: Int
        ): List<Place>?
```

To get results with pagination with native query, you just have to supply a count query as well -

```
@Query(
    value = """SELECT *, earth_distance(ll_to_earth(:latitude, :longitude), ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude)) distance 
                    FROM place 
                    WHERE earth_distance(ll_to_earth(:latitude, :longitude), ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude)) < :radiusInMeters                        
                    """,
    countQuery = """
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM place WHERE (earth_box(ll_to_earth(:latitude, :longitude), :radiusInMeters) @> ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude))
    """, nativeQuery = true)
fun getPlacesNear(
    pageable: Pageable,
    @Param("latitude") latitude: Double,
    @Param("longitude") longitude: Double,
    @Param("radiusInMeters") radiusInMeters: Int
): Page<Place>
```